# How to clear GridView while working with Firestore?

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, google-cloud-firestore, glide-golang

The problem is that I can't refresh my `gridView` and when I make changes in Firestore, my gridView doesn't clear and just adds new values(images) from Firestore. I have tried lots of methods that I could find on "stackoverflow" but with no success. Maybe the problem is with `ImageAdapter` or with how I call `addSnapshotListener`, I really don't know. Right now I just want that I can refresh my gridView when data changes on `Firestore`, but in best case scenario I want that, when I get new values from `Firestore`, it only updates that part of gridView where was the image,  and not the whole `gridView`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseFirestore db;
private ArrayList<Items> arrayList;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
private GridView gridView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridViewList);
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    //arrayList.clear();

    getUrls();

    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayList);
    gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

}

private void getUrls(){
    gridView.setAdapter(null);
    db.collection("images").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot value, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No images returned", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : value){
                refresh();
                if (document.get("imageUrl") != null){
                    arrayList.add(new Items(document.get("imageUrl").toString()));
                    refresh();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}


public void refresh() {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            gridView.invalidate();
        }
    });
}
```

---

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ImageView imageView;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<Items> list;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Items> list){
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null){
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_layout, parent, false);
        imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.singleImageView);
    }

    /** https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics */
    Glide.with(context).load(list.get(position).getImageUrl()).apply(RequestOptions.skipMemoryCacheOf(true).centerCrop()).into(imageView);
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [FirebaseUI-Android/Firestore](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/README.md) project has an adapter that does what you want. This does the heavy lifting of managing a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) for you. In order to have a layout like in `GridView`, you can create an instance of [`GridLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) in `onCreate` and pass that to [`RecyclerView.setLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager))

If you want to hack it yourself, the `QuerySnapshot` has a property `documentChanges` that you can check for `REMOVED` - cf. [View changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots). To get an idea of how it would be implemented with a `GridView` you can look at the source code of [`RecyclerView.Adatper`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/5f1c90f/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java#3970) - epecially the `notifyItemXXX` methods.

Comment: The problem about `FirebaseUI` is that it only works for `RecyclerView`. I'm trying to make it work for `gridView`. And talking about `documentChanges `, after each change like `REMOVED `I just call `imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            gridView.invalidate();` or it isn't that simple, because I need to call this method`arrayList.add(new Items(document.get("imageUrl").toString())); `

Comment: It would really be much faster to use `RecyclerView` and I have updated the answer to elaborate.

Comment: I should also add that in general there is nothing wrong with your approach - there are just many cases to consider. You might want to start from `ArrayAdapter` and not from `BaseAdapter`. That handles the list for you so that it's easier to remove the right item from your `arrayList`.

Comment: Tanks for help, using `FirebaseUI` worked for me. But I have one problem, that I don't know how to fix. How do I make, when I want to go from 2nd activity to my `FirebaseUI` activity, that layout doesn't reload and keeps last position where I have stop on `RecyclerView`?